# regex for not start with 'the' or end with 'form'.Input may have 'the' key word or end with 'form'

Tags: regex

regex for not start with 'the' or end with 'form'.The input may have 'the' keyword or end with 'form',
some input may have both the or form is missing.

eg:

```
the test3211 form - not valid
the test22 - not valid
test34 - valid
test55 form - not valid
```

So far I tried regex:  `^the.*form$`

Comment: Kindly do mention which language you are looking for regex? Also please do add your efforts in form of code in your question, which is highly encouraged on SO, thank you.

Comment: @Hetal Thaker Yes.  either both "the" and "form" should occur or not .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
^(?=the.*form$|(?!the|.*form$)).*$
```

- `^(?=...)` positive look ahead, checking form the beginning
- `the.*form$` either the string starts with `the` and ends with `form`
- `|(?!the|.*form)` or the string *neither start with `the`* nor *ends with `form`*

See the [proof](https://regex101.com/r/8UdJ0z/1/)

---

#### Edit

If you want none of them appears, it would be much simpler, try

```
^(?!the|.*form$).*$
```

- `(?!the|.*form$)` the string must neither start with `the` nor end with `form`

Check the [proof](https://regex101.com/r/NI8Siw/1/)

Comment: test55 form - failed,
the fund - failed

Comment: Isn't `test55 form` not supposed to pass? Or do you mean `test55 form - failed the fund`? It does not start with `the` and end with `form` so it should pass? I'm confused

Comment: from my question only test34 is valid. see my example from the question.

Comment: But you also listed `the test3211 form - valid` as valid

Comment: oh, I just update the example..it was my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need anchors and lookarounds:

```
^(?!the\b)(?!.*\bform$).+$
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/Mh7jqH/1).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I've understood your question correctly.

- The string can't start with 'the' or end with 'form'
- The string can contain 'the' or 'form' within the string

After some quick testing I came up with the following:

```
^(?!the).*(?<!form)$
```

Basically, this uses a negative lookahead to rule out any string starting with 'the'
Then it matches any number of characters until finally using a negative lookbehind to rule out any string ending with 'form'

All of these concepts are explained in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:AutoWikiBrowser/Regular_expression

Also check out [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/) for testing your regexes.